# .Net: Adding files and folders to SETUP Project programmatically

Tags: .net, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

So, here is the scenario:

> I want to create a installer which
>   would just dump few files and folders
>   at a location specified by user. But
>   the problem is these files are
>   required to be picked up from a fixed
>   source folder and then the installer
>   is build. Also, these files may change any time and then again a new version of the installer is required to be created.

So this needs to be done programmatically.

Also, how can I add some coding stuff in setup projects? (New to SETUP PROJECTS)

How? Any ideas/comments appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a windows application with several forms doing all the required stuff. This windows application behaved like a Setup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using standard Visual Studio Setup projects?

Have you looked into [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)?

WiX projects are written in XML and can be built with msbuild so you should be able to generate the xml and build the installers programmatically.